# Can a builder class declared with @Builder be referred directly?

Tags: groovy, compiler-errors

The following Groovy script fails to compile:

```
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder

@Builder
class Foo {
    String bar
}

Foo.FooBuilder aBuilder = Foo.builder()
```

The compile error is:

> Error:(8, 16) Groovyc: unable to resolve class Foo.FooBuilder

Is this expected behaviour? Any known workarounds?

Groovy version: 2.5.2 (I checked 2.4.12 and 2.4.15 too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. The line

```
Foo.FooBuilder aBuilder = Foo.builder()
```

will fail during [`Phases.SEMANTIC_ANALYSIS`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/Phases.java#L35) phase which tries to resolve all expected types (the ones declared on the left side). This phase gets executed before [`Phases.CLASS_GENERATION`](https://github.com/apache/groovy/blob/GROOVY_2_4_X/src/main/org/codehaus/groovy/control/Phases.java#L38) which generates `FooBuilder` class - that is why compiler complains about non-existing `FooBuilder` class (it was simply not generated yet).

#### Workaround

There is one simple workaround to this problem - use `def` and type inference to pass semantic analysis phase and let the compiler generate `FooBuilder` class.

```
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder

@Builder
class Foo {
    String bar
}

def aBuilder = Foo.builder()

println aBuilder.dump()
```

Just as a side note - there is one way to make `Foo.FooBuilder aBuilder = Foo.builder()`
 pass static analysis phase. If you skip declaring `Foo.FooBuilder` type

```
import groovy.transform.builder.Builder

@Builder
class Foo {
    String bar
}

//Foo.FooBuilder aBuilder = Foo.builder()
```

and compile this class with `groovyc` compiler, it will generate `Foo.class` as well as `Foo$FooBuilder.class`. Then if you uncomment the line that throws compilation exception and you run the script, it will compile and run without any issue. The trick is that Groovy compiler compiles `Foo.FooBuilder` class (and saves it as `Foo$FooBuilder.class` file), so when you run the script and the static analysis tries to resolve it, it is available in the current classpath. In this case semantic analysis phase does not report the error you faced earlier. However, I mention it only as a interesting fact and not a workaround, because it is pretty hard to work with. Using `def` keyword instead and relying on type inference works best in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I though so it has something to do with the compilation phases order. Using def won't help in my case. The snippet I posted in the question is the minimal example to show the issue. I wanted to use the Foo.FooBuilder class for a field annotated with @Delegate, it won't work with def. The same way I'm using it with Java builders to extend them and make a handy DSLs for creating object trees at tests.
Not sure if it's possible to re-order the phases to allow this. I've raised a bug on Groovy issue tracker: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-8803